# Xcode 6.1.1 not Auto-Complete

Tags: xcode, frameworks, completion

the last time I opened xCode 6.1.1, auto code completion stop working. It seems like it does not import Frameworks, even if are wrote.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm so confused. I tried re-install xCode, delete "Derive Data" and "Caches"...

Answer (score -1):

Press Control and Space at the same time and it should do the trick.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/CompletingCode.html

Comment: It simply displays Spotlight. To be more clear, as you can see the suggestions pop-up but not those for e.g. "UIKit" or "MapKit", only those with "M" (method)?